# Set an "unattainable" drop down list background to be over other elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have an autocomplete function which works fine, but when the drop down list appears, it is almost unreadable because it is over other elements.

The problem is that i don't create the drop down list myself, it is created from a request sent to a database and i can't manage to identify exactly which element's property i have to modify in order to have a dropdown box that would be like a block displayed over the other elements.

I tried to identify which elements were created when the dropdown list appears but it doesn't seem to do anything. Here's my result :

[image]

and the css part i coded :

```
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
z-index: 1000;
display: block;
background: #f9f9f9;
border-top: 1px solid blue;
```

}

The Autocomplete function ( not sure if it helps but doesn't cost anything to put it here )

```
// Auto-Complete sur liste publicitaire
$("#ag_pub_publicitaire_nompublicitaire").autocomplete
({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax
        ({
            url: "https://cms.ag-carto.com/CMS_service/ws_ag_sgbdr_json/ag_sgbdr.asmx/ag_pub_publicitaire_get_list",
            data: "{'ag_sql_query_text':'"  + request.term + "','count':'0'}",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
            success: function (data) {
                var found = $.map(data.d, function (item) {
                    return {
                        value: item.ag_pub_publicitaire_nompublicitaire,
                        ag_pub_publicitaire_entityid: item.ag_pub_publicitaire_entityid,
                    };
                });
                if (found.length == 0) {
                    $('#ag_pub_publicitaire_nompublicitaire').val("Pas de publicitaire Trouvé ! Ressaisissez...");
                    $('#ag_pub_publicitaire_entityd').val("");
                    //alert("Pas de publicitaire Trouvé ! Ressaisissez...");
                }
                else {
                    //$('#infopconso').val(found.length + " Compteurs Trouvés ! Choisissez dans la liste...");
                    //$('#infopconso').val(found.length + " Compteurs Trouvés ! Choisissez dans la liste...");
                }

                response(found);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
            {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 3,
    select: function (event, ui) 
    {
        if (ui.item.ag_pub_publicitaire_nompublicitaire == "-1") {
            $('#ag_pub_publicitaire_nompublicitaire').val("");
            $('#ag_pub_publicitaire_entityd').val("");
            $('#ag_pub_publicitaire_nompublicitaire').focus();
        }
        else {
            $("#ag_pub_publicitaire_entityid").val(ui.item.ag_pub_publicitaire_entityid);
        }
    }
});
```

Right now i think that i'm not aiming at the right class, but i don't really know what to try next. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks in advance and have a great day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really proud of this one but I didn't included the jquery-ui.css file in my html, that's why it it didn't work the way I wanted

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting wrong div css..

**Here is the fix** .Its targeting the ul with id #ui-id-1 which is showing the autocomplete fucntionallity..

```
 .ui-widget.ui-widget-content {
    z-index: 1000;
display: block;
background: #f9f9f9;
border-top: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Can you give me a working fiddle.? Because this is how UI Autocomplete works.. may be there is some structural problem in your code..

Comment: I'd like to but my boss doesn't want me to put the full code on internet since it contains "private informations" that he doesn't want to display :/

Comment: can you tell me where are you adding this css?

Comment: In a css file that is in the same folder as my other files